# Rasa core train command: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, rasa-core

I was following the tutorial from the rasa's official documentation page.
Rasa core's training command shows the following error:

```
usage: train.py [-h] [--model [MODEL]]
train.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -s data/stories.md -o models/dialogue -c cofing/nlu_config.yml
```

I have looked through the rasa Core's run.py file here https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/master/rasa_core/run.py. The command line argument for '-s' (stories) does not seem to exist.

This is the command that I ran in the terminal( as given in the tutorial ): `python -m rasa_core.train -s data/stories.md -o models/dialogue -c cofing/nlu_config.yml`

I am new to Rasa as well as stack Overflow, any help would be appreciated as I am unable to figure out this noob yet seeming unsolvable problem.

Comment: Additionally, this is the optional arguments list when I type `python -m rasa_core.train -h` on the shell : `usage: train.py [-h] [--model [MODEL]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --model [MODEL]  model timestamp format - YearMonthDay-HourMinuteSecond`

Comment: Update: It seems that I had a **test.py** file in the working directory which was getting invoked by the `rasa_core.train` automatically. Renaming the **test.py** solved the problem and brought back the functionalities of the command line arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python -m rasa_core.train -s data/stories.md -d domain.yml -o models/dialogue  -c policy.yml
```

You are missing the domain file.